# Set proper paths for VS Command Line Compiler

Tags: windows, visual-studio, batch-file

I recently installed vs15 - preview (Stripped down version of visual studio 2015). 
I am able to compile  C/C++ sources from inside the IDE, but I am not able to compile with the command line interface cl.exe. It can't find the c stdlib headers. I tried to use vcvars32.bat to set the proper reg values but seemingly it cant find the "Common Tools Folder".

"ERROR: Cannot determine the location of the VS Common Tools folder."

The script uses the env. variable "%VS150COMNTOOLS%". 
If I try to run "cd %VS150COMNTOOLS%" from the cmd line, it can't find the path, so this seems to be the main problem. 
How can manually set %VS150COMNTOOLS% to the right path? how can I set the cmd linker settings manually (Without telling the cl.exe every time I call it)?

Comment: I got the same problem. I tried to add VS150COMNTOOLS to env variables but it didnt help. I filled an issue to Microsoft, hope they'll fix it

Comment: As stated in this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/03/06/finding-the-visual-c-compiler-tools-in-visual-studio-2017/) "VS150COMNTOOLS" is not used anymore. But you can use vswhere or powershell to found the Visual Studio 2017 path (top of the article).

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I solved it by adding the path to the include directories and lib directories to the env. variables as "INCLUDE", "LIB". It works now, whyever the script was not able to set those values properly. I am not fluent in reading .bat let away writing in, I assume the directory structure, which is different for the vs15 preview when compared to the full version, had not been adapted yet.